# how to create a file with 9983137 columns containing 0/0?

Tags: unix, vim

i'm not good in programming, so i'm asking the very basic question :
how to create a file with 9983137 columns, each one containing 0/0 ?

I tried it using vim but I didn't succeed..
Some help would be appreciated, thanks in advance,

vschill

Comment: Columns or rows?? 9983137 seems to be a lot for a line.

Comment: I'm talking about lines, indeed.. one column and 9983137 lines. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This'll create a bunch of comma separated columns in vim:

```
9983137i0/0, <esc>:w ~/temp.csv^M
```

Inserts the text `0/0,<space>` 9983137 times and then saves it as a `.csv` in your root folder.

Comment: @user3498791 if the answer solved your question, do you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'print "0\0 " for (1..9983137) ;' > largefile.txt
```

to verify use the `wc` command on the generated file

Answer (score 0):

in vim (I didn't test, and I won't do a test ^_^):

```
vim foo (open an empty file)

9983137i0/0<esc>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know why, I don't have 9983137 lines but something like 3300155... One thing I don't understand is that I have to make Ctrl+C after your command, because even if one hour after, it looks like nothing happened.

Comment: @user3498791 you don't want to have xxx lines, you wanted columns right? and... I thought of that problem, that's why I wrote "I won't do a test".. :)

Comment: In fact I would like to xxx lines, each one with 0/0 .. Maybe if I'm doing :  9983137i0/0 <enter> <esc> ?

Comment: you can first type in one new line: `0/0` then `<ESC>Y555p` the `555` you can replace with your ideal number, like `9983137...` @user3498791 or `555O0/0<ESC>`